# click event for links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML and JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>        
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#foo" id="bar">Something</a>
    <div id="foo></div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $link = $("#bar");
            $link[0].click(function() {
                alert("Whatever.");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[This article](https://makandracards.com/makandra/17267-trigger-a-link-s-click-action-with-javascript) explains the approach. However it's not working - no alertbox shows. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you fix the markup in your question?

Comment: Done. Sorry, thought I needed to use HTML entities.

Comment: I've fixed it Tim @ksav

Comment: Due to my blindness I sometimes get indentations wrong, too. Looks like you fixed that as well. Thanks for that. Hope it's readable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `$link[0]` will return native element not jQuery object, use `onclick` event or `addEventListener('click', ....)`

```js
$(function() {
  $link = $("#bar");
  $link[0].onclick = function() {
    alert("Whatever.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#foo" id="bar">Something</a>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

and the correct way to select element by index using jQuery is using `eq()`

```js
$(function() {
  $link = $("#bar");
  $link.eq(0).click(function() {
    alert("Whatever.");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#foo" id="bar">Something</a>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

please note that selector `ID` will only return 1 element so you can use second index or greater.

Comment: After quite some contemplating I decided to accept this one as it answers my specific question based on the article - all suggested solutions work however.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the [0] array index from the code and make sure to close div id quotes:

```html
<html>        
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <a href="#foo" id="bar">Something</a>
        <div id="foo"></div>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $link = $("#bar");
                $link.click(function() {
                    alert("Whatever.");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the article they said href wouldn't get executed in this case, however?

Comment: I think you responded to the wrong person but the article is incorrect.  It does follow through to the "link" but the link is an "anchor tag" which is shown because of the # in the href of the link.  This means it will look for the ID foo on the page and scroll the page to it.  So in theory it scrolls to your foo div on the page when clicked.  You won't notice it on a small page but you can see it jump around if you expand it where the user has to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to not open link but only alert any text you can try to write script something like that:

```
$('#bar').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Whatever.');
})
```

Comment: I would probably either skip using a link entirely and style the element with CSS or use the href="#!" hack vs this method personally.  Not sure if there's a huge difference in doing so in this case, though.

Comment: @Nathan Champion I'm agree, IMHO the best way is just use another element (like div or span) and style it with css in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `id` as a common selector than you are doing bad, please use `class` for common selector else you don't need to do something like `$(id)[0]`. Also, make a habit of unbinding the event once the binding is done.

```
$(function() {
    $link = $("#bar");
    $link.off('click').on('click', function() {
        let $this = $(this);
        let href = $this.attr('href');
        alert("href " + href);
    });
});
```